# RingCentral Subscription is not picking up on any activity of calls

Tags: node.js, ringcentral, ringcentral-webhooks

I'm running in Node.js.

My app is not picking up on any call action after successful subscription to `/account/~/telephony/sessions`

My Code:

```js
    function setSubscription() {
    const platform = rcsdk.platform()
    platform.login({
        username: '+14706150273',
        extension: '101',
        password: '********'
    }).then(response => {
        const subscription = rcsdk.createSubscription().setEventFilters(['/account/~/telephony/sessions']);
        subscription.on(subscription.events.notification, function (msg) {
            console.log(msg);
        });
        subscription.register().then(function (response) {
            console.log(response.json());
            console.log('Success: Subscription is listening');
        }).catch(function (e) {
            console.log('Subscription Error: ' + e.message);
        });
    }).catch(e => {
        console.error(e)
    })
}
```

Console output after run showing successfully subscribed (but nothing after) - Calls are showing in the sandbox call log:

```
[nodemon] starting `node index.js`
Server is running on port: 5000
{
  uri: 'https://platform.devtest.ringcentral.com/restapi/v1.0/subscription/edde4bf6-1563-4263-94c7-247954e3ac68',
  id: 'edde4bf6-1563-4263-94c7-247954e3ac68',
  creationTime: '2021-11-16T22:52:03.946Z',
  status: 'Active',
  eventFilters: [ '/restapi/v1.0/account/307128004/telephony/sessions' ],
  expirationTime: '2021-11-16T23:07:03.946Z',
  expiresIn: 899,
  deliveryMode: {
    transportType: 'PubNub',
    encryption: false,
    address: '4174641560134678_4a93035d',
    subscriberKey: 'sub-c-b8b9cd8c-e906-11e2-b383-02ee2ddab7fe'
  }
}
Success: Subscription is listening
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone that has this issue - make sure you have only 1 subscription of the same kind at a time. Multiple will create an issue.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).